# Chain Jenkins Promotion Jobs (Different Builds\Same Environment)

Tags: jenkins, chain, promoted-builds

Suppose one has several Jenkins jobs (e.g., Job1, Job2, Job3) and the Promoted Builds plugin is installed.

Each job has a different latest build:

Job1 - #26 
Job2 - #2 
Job3 - #7

The Promoted Builds plugin lets one promote each of these builds - individually - to a specified environment.

However, what's the best way to set up a separate job that will sequentially promote the latest build from each job to a specified environment?

For example, suppose I want to sequentially promote the latest build from Job1, Job2, and Job3 to the QA environment.  Is it possible to create Job4, which allows me to specify the environment and will promote the latest build to it from Jobs1-3?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: that's a pretty complex use case. i will upvote that. i have not used Promoted Builds, but one option would be to start reading about pipelines (Jenkinsfiles). you put jam that entire use case into one pipeline with multiple stages, or you could use the pipeline step `build` to build other jobs. or maybe the promoted builds plugin let's you promote over the API, so you could do that, wait for each promotion to compete, and then hammer the next.